# System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type

Tags: c#, macos, web-services, mono

Ok firstly I am using mono on mac osx, I'm trying to consume a web service from http://arf.webservice.sportsflash.com.au/WebService.asmx

I followed a tutorial that uses another web service, that worked fine. Basically I create a dll from the above site using "wdsl http://arf.webservice.sportsflash.com.au/WebService.asmx/?WSDL" then i try to call it in my class file and i get like 100 lines of errors.

```
GetFixtureResponseGetFixtureResult results;

// Create a Currency Convertor object
AFL Service1 = new AFL ();

// Actually call the method
results = Service1.GetFixture(1);
Console.WriteLine("Rate is {0}",results);
```

This is the fragment of code I'm using, compiler starts with this.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'GetPlayerStatsResponseGetPlayerStatsResult'.
>    ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'Any'.
>    ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The element Any has been attributed with an XmlAnyElementAttribute and a namespace '', but no name. When a namespace is supplied, a name is also required. Supply a name or remove the namespace.

Any help would be appreciated.

Furthering, the only other commands I'm using are:

- to create the dll:

  ```
  mcs /target:library AFL.cs -r:System.Web.Services
  ```
- to compile:

  ```
  mcs /r:AFL.dll test.cs -r:System.Web.Services
  ```

Here is the linked tutorial:
http://mono-project.com/Consuming_a_WebService